# Ajax in wordpress plugin working on apache but not nginx

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nginx

I hate to ask this question here but I’ve exhausted all other resources. And I’ve searched everywhere but can’t find any help.

I’m migrating my WordPress site from an Apache server to the nginx server. And one of the plug-ins I used on my Apache server was roksprocket.

http://www.rockettheme.com/wordpress/plugins/roksprocket

When I install roksprocket on a fresh install of the nginx the plug-in refuses to work. When I hit any save button nothing at all happens.

A quick look into Chrome's Dev tools console shows the following javascript error every time I press the save button:

`Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

But when I install wordpress with roksprocket on a fresh apache server…. no issues.

I have a feeling that something is missing in the nginx config stopping the plug-in from getting a proper ajax response. Here are the headers sent and received:

`

```
    Remote Address:example.com:80

    Request URL:http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=roksprocket&nonce=4e79d82c02

    Request Method:POST

    Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:158
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:wordpress_8d5c55f263f1fbeaeacab59de0ed539f=webmaster%7C1399299571%7Cc45cc66c20278417596ac7a86a44f14c; gantry-android-switcher=1; PHPSESSID=lc8g3abuip5geje0mfq9c2m0v2; wp-settings-time-1=1399126752; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_8d5c55f263f1fbeaeacab59de0ed539f=webmaster%7C1399299571%7C9762057a27f2113db6f91e2435df4d87; roksprocket-showitems=1; gantry-android-switcher=1; wp-settings-time-3=1399174698
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=roksprocket-edit&nonce=4e79d82c02&paged=1&id=0
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Query String Parameters
action:roksprocket
nonce:4e79d82c02

Form Data
id:0
uuid:eb62825b-8b2c-4251-cd0b-ddcfabf45c5c
title:test
params[provider]:wordpress
params[layout]:tabs
task:
model:edit
model_action:save
model_encoding:form

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 04 May 2014 03:38:37 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Robots-Tag:noindex
```

`NGINX.CONF`

```
 user www-data;
 worker_processes auto;
 pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Easy Engine Settings
    ##

    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Powered-By EasyEngine;
    add_header rt-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";

    # Limit Request 
    limit_req_status 403;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    # Proxy Settings 
    # set_real_ip_from      proxy-server-ip;
    # real_ip_header        X-Forwarded-For;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # SSL Settings
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    log_format rt_cache '$remote_addr $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] '
                '$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;


    fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:50m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_cache_valid any 1h;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers  Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    # Common Upstream Settings
    upstream php {
        # server unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    upstream debug {
        # Debug Pool
        server 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

`

example.com.conf
`

```
server {

    # Uncomment The Following Line For Domain Mapping
    # listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    # Uncomment The Following Line For Domain Mapping
    #server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    set $cache_uri $request_uri;

    # POST Requests And Urls With A Query String Should Always Go To PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't Cache Uris Containing The Following Segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|index.php|/feed/|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't Use The Cache For Logged In Users Or Recent Commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Use Cached Or Actual File If They Exists, Otherwise Pass Request To WordPress
    location / {
        try_files /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/wp-content/cache/minify/(.+\.(css|js))$ {
        try_files $uri /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    # WordPress Common Settings
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "localhost";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With";

    # Limit Access To Avoid Brute Force Attack
    location = /wp-login.php {
        limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    # Disable wp-config.txt
    location = /wp-config.txt {
        deny  all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Disallow PHP In Upload Folder
    location /wp-content/uploads/ {
        location ~ \.php$ {
            #Prevent Direct Access Of PHP Files From Web Browsers
            deny all;
        }
    }
    # Basic Locations Files
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Cache Static Files For As Long As Possible
    location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }


    # Security Settings For Better Privacy

    # Deny Hidden Files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Deny Backup Extensions & Log Files
    location ~* ^.+\.(bak|log|old|orig|original|php#|php~|php_bak|save|swo|swp)$ {
        deny  all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Return 403 Forbidden For readme.(txt|html) or license.(txt|html)
    if ($request_uri ~* "^.+(readme|license)\.(txt|html)$") {
        return 403;
    }


    # Status Pages
    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        satisfy any;
        auth_basic "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd-ee;

        # Allowed IP Address List
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(status|ping) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        satisfy any;
        auth_basic "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd-ee;

        # Allowed IP Address List
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }


    # EasyEngine Admin Tools

    # PMA Settings
    location /pma {
        return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
    }

    # Adminer Settings
    location /adminer {
            return 301 https://$host:22222/db/adminer;
    }

}
```

`

Comment: could you include your nginx config? it seems many apache->nginx conversions fail around rewrites and htaccess files (nginx does not use htaccess)

Comment: Added the configs, thank you very much for replying